# How can I open an aspx page in a new browser window from a SilverLight Application?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to add a button to my user control in SilverLight 4.0 application which will open a new browser window with an aspx in it when it is clicked.

How can I achieve this, can you please advice?

Additionaly, can I lock the SL application until this new window is closed (Alike a modal dialog)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a new window with:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uriToNewPage, "_blank");
```

However modal dialogs depend on the specific browser that is hosting.
Internet Explorer and Firefox both have a `showModalDialog` method on their `window` objects.  You would need to use the `Invoke` method to fire these:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showModalDialog", urlString);
```

Comment: Well that saves me looking up the HtmlPage code now (*spoilsport*) :)

Comment: @burak ozdogan: Go with what AnthonyWJones says :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HyperlinkButton control. You can specify to open in a new tab or new browser window.

(There is also a navigate option available from the Http class, but I will have to look up the syntax).

To do the modal popup scenario, you would need to generate a popup in Javascript on the browser hosting the SL control (which you *can* trigger from within Silverlight).